# Read value from csv

Tags: bash, shell, parsing, awk

For a csv file appearing as:

```
variables = cl, cd, clp, clv, cdp, cdv, ...  
-0.00000002, 0.01023266, -0.00000002, 0.00000000, 0.00985099, 0.00038167, ...  
-0.00000000, 0.01023305, -0.00000000, 0.00000000, 0.00985080, 0.00038225,  
-0.00000002, 0.01023390, -0.00000002, 0.00000000, 0.00985075, 0.00038315,  
0.00000002, 0.01023482, 0.00000002, 0.00000000, 0.00985070, 0.00038412,  
-0.00000004, 0.01023574, -0.00000004, 0.00000000, 0.00985065, 0.00038509,
```

...

I have a short script to read values from a csv file, but as it is, it returns the entire column. I need it to assign a single value to each variable.

```
export IFS=","
cat file.csv | while read a b c d e f; do echo "$b; done
```

This returns:

```
cd  
0.01023266  
0.01023305  
0.01023390  
0.01023482  
0.01023574
```

How do I make this command return only:

0.01023482

Edit:
The following line is supposed to return a single value from my file:

```
row=4
col=2
str=$(awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} FNR==$row' history.out | awk  '{print substr($col, 1, length($col)-1)}')
echo $str
```

It works when I use $4, but not $row. What's the final fix? As it is, $str is returned empty.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is always advisable to add Sample of input file too, so please do add it in your post and let us know then.

Comment: What's the criteria for returning that line? Its position in the file, or the value in one or the other column?

Comment: `bash` is only appropriate for this (and just barely) if your CSV file doesn't have escaped commas of any kind in a field. If you have a line like `a,"b,c",d`, then `bash` isn't really up to recognizing this as having 3, rather than 4, columns.

Comment: Please do add your file.csv sample and sample output in your question and do let us know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***EDIT:*** Since OP has shown samples now so adding solution as per it now.

```
row=4
col=2
awk -v R="$row" -v C="$col" 'BEGIN{FS=","} FNR==R{print $C}'  Input_file
```

Change `FS=","` to `FS=", "` in case you have space in your comma delimiters too.

---

---

This could be easily done in `awk`.

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} FNR==4' Input_file
```

Comment: @BrendanMcBreen, Please edit your post with samples and lemme know then?

Comment: Once the data format is shown @RavinderSingh13 will be able to show how a simple command substitution with `awk` will save the columns and line of data you desire to a variable. But, the format matters. Whitespace around the delimiters?, etc...

Comment: @BrendanMcBreen, Could you please check my EDIT solution and lemme know if that helps you?

Comment: Ravinder, it works flawlessly. You're a god. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @BrendanMcBreen, Its all Almighty's grace on me, I am also common person like you, cheers and keep sharing, learning on this great site SO, cheers.